# Rosh Hashanah cooking

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, chagim-holidays, high-holidays

Since one is allowed to cook on all Yom tov (except Yom Kippur) that doesn’t fall on Shabbat for that day of Yom tov, and since Rosh Hashanah is two days (but halachically one), could one cook on the first day of Rosh Hashanah for the second day since it is considered one big Yom Tov?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two days of Rosh Hashana are like every other two day holiday in this regard (OC 503:1).